# How do you use kwargs to map (k, v) pairs in a dict to a given sqlalchemy table?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, keyword-argument

How could I use `*args`/`**kwargs` to map (k, v) pairs from a given Python dict to an sqlalchemy Table object?

From what I can tell, sqlalchemy objects inheriting from `sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base` allow for objects to be bound from dicts using `kwargs`, or via a series of `setattr()` calls as follows:

```
report = session.query(Report).get(report_id)
for k, v in r.iteritems():
    setattr(report, k, v)
```

However my models are inheriting from `sqlalchemy.MetaData`, as follows, using `sqlalchemy.orm` to map a class to a given table. If this complicates matters, I am open to switching to the low-level API.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, MetaData, Table, Integer, String, Date, orm
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

metadata = MetaData()

class Report(object):
    pass

reports_table = Table('reports', metadata,
                      Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                      Column('probe_asn', String(8)),
                      Column('probe_cc', String(3)),
                      Column('probe_ip', String(40)),
                      Column('report', postgresql.JSON),

orm.mapper(Report, reports_table)

def create_all(engine):
    metadata.create_all(engine)
```

---

Currently, I am setting each property from the dict individually and this works, yet, this is undesirable.

```
def insert_reports(session, reports):
    """
    :param session: an instance of a given sqlalchemy session
    :param reports: an array of reports
    :return:
    """
    for report in reports:
        r = schema.Report()
        r.probe_asn = report['probe_asn']
        r.probe_cc = report['probe_cc']
        r.probe_ip = report['probe_ip']
        r.report = report['report']

        session.add(r)
    else:
        session.commit()
```

How could I map a given dict to a given sqlalchemy table object, using `*args`/`**kwargs` or `setattr()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpacking the `report` dictionary should do the trick:

```
session.add(schema.Report(**report))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot later today. This is in-line with my original assumption with regards to how to use **kwargs. Do you think this would break if the dict has a property that the table does not?

Comment: @hodgepodge yup, I'm pretty sure it'll break. We can filter out keys corresponding to only existing columns actually, let me know if we need to do that. Thanks.